# Search Data between excel and csv file python- its like vlookup

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, vlookup

Stack Members, I am very new to this site, please bear with me for my question and the format :)

I have two files - one CSV and one Excel(From here i have to search)

CSV looks like below:

```
aips           process  port
111.230.36.78   qmt     234

"169.254.95.120
10.96.9.10 "     qwe    890

12.4.5.2.4      mnb     987
89.56.7.8.1     hbgs    abc
```

Excel Looks Like

```
Address        code
12.4.5.2.4     LMN
111.230.36.78  PQR

"16.24.15.120
100.6.9.10"    XYZ

110.20.7.200   sqm
```

I want out put like below. In short I want to search for **code** in excel file through aips(in csv) and Address(in excel)- both are ip's and then add the found **code** in the csv file.

```
aips          service   port    code
111.230.36.78   qmt     234     PQR

"169.254.95.120
 10.96.9.10"        qwe     890     XYZ

12.4.5.2.4      mnb     987     LMN
89.56.7.8.1     hbgs    7876    NA
```

I am trying to write python code for this but not able to recall how can I apply vlookup here. Can any one help me with the code. I want to read it and understand. If I get this I can apply with my modification as required. This is just a dummy process I want to learn please. I have read other stack questions and solution but not able to get it correctly.I have seen pandas library but very new to it not able to implement it.

When doing 
`df1['code'] = df1['aips'].map(df2.set_index('Address')['code'])`
getting below error

```
base.py", line 2684, in get_indexer raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely' series.py", line 2309, in map indexer = arg.index.get_indexer(values)
```

To fix index issue i tried `reset` instead of `set` in above code, bit of no use.

Comment: One file is csv and other excel and both have first column name different - one Address and other aips

Comment: Yes, first use `df1 = pd.read_csv(file1)` and then `df2 = pd.read_excel(file2)`

Comment: Yeah, That I figured it out , but the column name is different for ip's in both files- in csv its aips and in excel its Address _ is there any way to get rid of ?

Comment: I saw you linked post _ `df1['id'].map(df2.set_index('id')['code'])` _ this should work ??  but I am worried about column name (although those both have ip's )  . In place of id - How i pass two columns(apis and Address) ?

Comment: I think `df1['code'] = df1['aips'].map(df2.set_index('Address')['code'])` should working nice here.

Comment: Error `base.py", line 2684, in get_indexer raise InvalidIndexError('Reindexing only valid with uniquely'
series.py", line 2309, in map indexer = arg.index.get_indexer(values)`

Comment: I read somewhere to use reset instead of set , so tried reset in the code given by you instead of set . But its not helpful.

Comment: there is problem duplicated values in `Address` column, so `map` fialed. For remove dupes need `df2 = df2.drop_duplicates('Address')`

Comment: Let me give it a try.

Comment: Its working but not sure if its covering all app or not, as i seen with the same IP I have few more apps that dinot got populated. I used `df1.to_csv('file1.csv', index=False)` to save the column after port column

Comment: I also want to avoid removing from the file, as that is the master file and used by many more people, thats why i tried reset but thats not working.

Comment: hmmm, there is logic problem - is impossible map by non unique `Address`. If add new row sample data are `110.20.7.200   value` then get for `110.20.7.200` 2 different values - `sqm, value`. So question is what need do?

Comment: Let me manually do it for few ips and application based on that output I will update you as well . Let me analyze,

Comment: Its working . I just found that ip-code are unique , other columns are varied and for that i got confused , but yes if i encountered ip-code not unique there may be issue. As of now my file do no have ununique ip-code. Just want to understand about the duplicated thing that you explained.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to mark your  comments thumbs up , seems I do not have option yet. but i really appreciate your time and help.

Comment: Sure! And also I will come back to this to up vote :)

Comment: Glad can help! Nice day!

Comment: You too have nice day sir !